Movie with contest where hands are put in a hole with snakes
I think this movie was from the 1980s or 1990s. I would have seen it in the early-mid 1990s when I was a child. It was in English and was in colour. It was either an American or British film. The only scene I remember was one where two men (possibly the hero and villain) were performing a contest. Each had to place their entire arm through a hole where snakes lay. I think the purpose was to determine their bravery.
The villainous character went first, but only pretended to put his arm fully in the hole. He never actually reached the snakes. I think the heroic character placed his arm in next and did go the whole way in, but at this point my memory of the scene and the rest of the film is non-existent.

I am not fully sure, but it rings a bell for both "Flash Gordon" and "Dune"... not certain enough about this for a full answer, though... may provide a lead though :)

It does sound very much like "Flash Gordon", though it was more of a scorpion-like creature than a snake, and I don't recall any subterfuge on the part of the other guy.

That scene in Flash Gordon made me squirm, and that's what I thought of immediately. I don't remember a scene like this from Dune; the main dude did stick his hand in a thing that gave him the experience of excruciating pain, but there were no snakes.

I can check them out folks, but do feel free to add answers if you think they're right!

hah.  I'd forgotten the guy from blue peter played with it first.

Flash Gordon, scene on Arboria: it is an initiation into manhood. Youth must put his hand into a tree trunk wherein lies a green alien scorpion thingy with a maddening poison. So not snakes but creature with poison stinger.  Dune is a box that is run by the queen mother that tests Paul Atriedes by controlling his mind and inflicting pain thru thought in the form of heat/ fire imagined but not real.
